# getting ORA-01407:cannot update to null error

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, oracle12c

i am getting ORA-01407:cannot update to null error for below query, Please help on this.

```
UPDATE PS_CT_IQN_ACC_STG stg
   SET (CTS_WO_ID,CTS_WO_END_DATE,CTS_WO_REG_RATE,CTS_WO_OT_RATE,VENDOR_ID) = (select CT_WORK_ORDER_ID,END_DATE,CT_WO_RATEREGULAR,CT_WO_RATEOVERTIME,CT_WO_VENDOR_ID from ps_cts_iqn_empl_wo WO1
where WO1.CT_WORK_ORDER_ID= (select max(CT_WORK_ORDER_ID) from ps_cts_iqn_empl_wo WO where WO.cts_peoplesoft_id = STG.EMPLID
   AND WO.ct_wo_project_id  = STG.project_id  and stg.report_due_date between WO.start_date and WO.end_date  )
   and WO1.lastupddttm = (select max(lastupddttm) from ps_cts_iqn_empl_wo WO2 where WO2.cts_peoplesoft_id = STG.EMPLID
   AND WO2.ct_wo_project_id  = STG.project_id  and stg.report_due_date between WO2.start_date and WO2.end_date  ))
```

Comment: share your sample output and table schema for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is updating the following 5 columns of the table `PS_CT_IQN_ACC_STG`:

```
CTS_WO_ID
CTS_WO_END_DATE
CTS_WO_REG_RATE
CTS_WO_OT_RATE
VENDOR_ID
```

`SELECT` Query to update the column values must be returning `NULL` for one of the columns for which `NOT NULL` constraint **OR** `check` of not null is applied.

You can check this from the following dictionary views:

```
USER_TAB_COLS -- NULLABLE column will be N for not null columns
USER_CONSTRAINTS -- Type will be C with Search_condition like <COLUMN_NAME> IS NOT NULL for not null columns.
```

Cheers!!